# 0x0000007b vista harddrive swap

Tags: windows-vista, command-line, boot, troubleshooting

I swap my hard drive to a new computer with vista 32
I get 0x0000007b stop error on bootup

I tried using the cd to do the repair but it fails.  I think it is because I have the wrong hard drive driver install for vista or it is missing.

How can I fix this from the command line

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that error is related to the mode your SATA controller is in. That error means Vista is trying to load the AHCI drivers, but the drive is not in AHCI mode. You should go into your bios and change the mode of the driver.

just as a note: windows machines generally do *not* like to be moved from one setup to another.

[Reference Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976)

Comment: +1 for Windows machines don't like to be uprooted.