# Booting From VHD Windows 7 Stop Error 0x0000007B

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, bsod, bootloader, vhd

I have created a a boot entry with EasyBCD 2.2, and I used a VHD that is on my C: partition. The VHD is Windows 7 Pro x86. Then I went to the edit boot menu to check that it was showing, and I hit save settings. I reboot my machine (my host machine is an Alienware 17 loaded with Windows 8 Pro x64, 16 GB Ram, Disk 1 is SSD 256 GB, Disk 2 HHD 750 GB) I found the boot option for Windows 7 and I selected it.

After that the Windows start up screen shows up, just for a sec, then throws the stop error: 0x0000007B

I looked up the stop error. It says it is about the hard drive controller. However the VHD boots just fine in my host machine. What I mean that it boots just fine is, I can open hyper-v on my Win 8 host, and connect to the VHD of Win 7 and run it just fine.

I have tried this link here:
[0x0000007b vista harddrive swap](https://superuser.com/questions/97925/0x0000007b-vista-harddrive-swap)

My Disk Drive Conntrolor is in AHCI Mode, I checked in BIOS.

I tired this link here:

[Booting a Windows 7 installation on different hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/54300/booting-a-windows-7-installation-on-different-hardware)

I tried to do a repair with the disc, and sysprep, I am still having the same error when I try to boot to the VHD.

Boot Info Here:

There are a total of 3 entries listed in the bootloader.

Default: Windows 8.1
Timeout: 6 seconds
EasyBCD Boot Device: C:\

Entry #1
Name: Windows 8.1
BCD ID: {current}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.exe

Entry #2
Name: Ubuntu 13.10
BCD ID: {3769cc0b-9327-11e3-82b4-240a646decc5}
Device: [C:]\Users\natem\Documents\Virtual Machines\Ubuntu 13.4\Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit.vhd
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.exe

Entry #3
Name: Win 7
BCD ID: {b922c6db-9330-11e3-82b9-f01faf470405}
Device: [C:]\Users\natem\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows 7 Pro 32.vhd
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.exe

Comment: This is the same problem people moving Windows from physical machine to (different) physical machine encounter -- HDD controller/chipset mismatches.  The HDD controller driver for the Hyper-V VM is not the same one your Host machine requires when booting natively form the VHD.  You need to get the host's HDD controller's driver into the image.  There are many questions covering this on here already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [0x0000007b vista harddrive swap](http://superuser.com/questions/97925/0x0000007b-vista-harddrive-swap)

Comment: (better) possible dupe: [Booting a Windows 7 installation on different hardware](http://superuser.com/questions/54300/booting-a-windows-7-installation-on-different-hardware)

Comment: @techie007 Thanks for the info, I didn't know that.

Comment: No problem -- good luck! :)

Comment: @techie007 I have tried what you have suggested, and it doesn't work in my case. I have updated the question. Also will you remove your flag for closing the question, since it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Did you do **sysprep /generalize** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to inject the correct AHCI driver.

diskpart 
and use the **ATTACH** command to mount the VHD file location.

select vdisk file=m:\test.vhdx

attach vdisk

select partition 1

assign letter = R:

DISM.exe /Image:R:\ /Add-Driver /Driver:d:\Drivers\ /Recurse

Obviously change **d:\Drivers** to match the path where the AHCI drivers are located.